# Ionic iOS build failing with phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uikit, phonegap-pushplugin

I have added the following package info in my package.json under `cordovaPlugins` array as the plugin documentation says.

```
{
  "variables": {
    "SENDER_ID": "XXXXXXX"
  },
  "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push"
}
```

However, the iOS build is failing and I'm unable to figure out what's wrong as I'm new to iOS app development. Here's the partial log that shows the error, which majorly says,

> 'UIRemoteNotificationType' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use UIUserNotificationType for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead

and more of similar logs talking about `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`, `UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` etcetera.

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I played around a little and updated my ionic and cordova CLI's,
also updated `ios-deploy` library and re-installed `iOS` platform. Things are working now.

I think `ios-deploy` was out dated.